# Why setting timezone on the Java calendar object has no effect?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

Consider the following code snippets.

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    System.out.println(tz);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2017, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);

    System.out.println("before setting time zone: " + cal.getTime());
    cal.setTimeZone(tz);

    System.out.println("after setting time zone: " + cal.getTime());
```

Here is the result:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
before setting time zone: Mon Dec 25 22:39:53 EST 2017 
after setting time zone: Mon Dec 25 22:39:53 EST 2017
```

After the timezone change, why is the printout of the date still showing EST?  Shouldn't it be GMT?

Comment: You set the zone on `cal` and not on `cal.getTime()`. Latter one is just of type `java.util.Date` where you cannot set the zone (and its method `java.util.Date.toString()` only uses the system tz).

Comment: Realizing that `cal.getTime()` gives you a `java.util.Date` this famous blog entry may help: [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.DECEMBER , 25 )
         .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
```

---

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy.

To directly answer your Question, the [`Calendar::getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) method returns a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). Among the many design flaws in these classes, [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--) dynamically applies your JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string. Thus your `EST` appearing.

Never use these classes. Use only their replacement, the industry-leading java.time classes.

## java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate xmas2017 = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.DECEMBER , 25 ) ;
```

If you want a date-time, the first moment of the day, you must specify a time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. **Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST`** or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Never assume the day starts at 00:00. In some zones, anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) means the day may start at some other time such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine the first moment of the day.

Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = xmas2017.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Note that Christmas starts much earlier in India than in New York.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkta = xmas2017.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

This is why the elves’ *Logistics* department route Santa to [Kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati) for his first deliveries. Those islands have the earliest Christmas with a time zone 14 hours ahead of UTC. From there the reindeer fly eastward chasing successive midnights, one after another, as the globe spins into the sunlight of a new day.

If you want that same moment adjusted into UTC, extract a `Instant` which is always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).